# Sum values by criteria in r

Tags: r

I have been trying to get this right but i cant find the right way to apporach this problem. Lets say i have some data that look like this:

```
hhid   totalplacevisited
1              5
1              6
1              2
2              2
2              4
3              1
```

How can i aggregate the data so i can get values in this format:

```
hhid   totalplacevisited   totalplacedvisitedbyhh
1              5                    13
1              6                    13
1              2                    13
2              2                    6
2              4                    6 
3              1                    1
```

Comment: “How can i aggregate” – fittingly, using `aggregate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is using `ave`

```
> transform(df, totalplacedvisitedbyhh = with(df,ave(totalplacevisited, hhid, FUN=sum)))
  hhid totalplacevisited totalplacedvisitedbyhh
1    1                 5                     13
2    1                 6                     13
3    1                 2                     13
4    2                 2                      6
5    2                 4                      6
6    3                 1                      1
```

Other alternative is using `data.table`

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(df)
> DT[, totalplacedvisitedbyhh := sum(totalplacevisited), by=hhid]
> DT
   hhid totalplacevisited totalplacedvisitedbyhh
1:    1                 5                     13
2:    1                 6                     13
3:    1                 2                     13
4:    2                 2                      6
5:    2                 4                      6
6:    3                 1                      1
```

Comment: Thanks the ave() worked great

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` package is the fastest way:

```
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,totalplacesvisitedbyhh:=sum(totalplacevisited),by=hhid]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution from plyr package

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydf,.(hhid),transform, totalplacedvisitedbyhh=sum(totalplacevisited))

 hhid totalplacevisited totalplacedvisitedbyhh
1    1                 5                     13
2    1                 6                     13
3    1                 2                     13
4    2                 2                      6
5    2                 4                      6
6    3                 1                      1
```